# CodePipeline with Multiple container ECS deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/ecs-cd-pipeline.html
I followed this amazon tutorial which allowed me to implement rolling updates for a cluster that contained a single service, taskDef and container. My deployment will have 2 or more services running X number of containers so I would like to get CodePipeline rolling updates working with multiple services.
To get rolling updates working with a cluster with 2 services, I

- Defined a second ECR.
- Referenced this ECR in the existing AmazonCloudWatchEventRule.
- Added an additional ECR action in CodePipeline sources stage.
- Added additional commands in buildspec.yaml

```
printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' $HTTPD_IMAGE_NAME $HTTPD_URI:latest > httpdimagedefinitions.json
```

```
printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' $NGINX_IMAGE_NAME $HTTPD_URI:latest > nginximagedefinitions.json
```

- Finally, added an additional ECS deploy action to update the second service.

This is working, however..
If I push to one ECR - both services' taskDefs get updated.
If I push to both ECRs at the same time, which will realistically happen within our Jenkinsfile - each services taskDef gets updated twice. taskDef 1 > taskDef 3.

Again, these aren't show stoppers especially in POC phase, but:

- Is it right to define more than one ECR sources..?
- Does anyone have any resources for implementing this. AWS docs from what I've seen only talk through managing a single service.